# Bash Run Script on Multiple Files

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a simple bash script running a command in ImageMagick. It takes an image (INFILE - typically a .tif), resizes it, and saves the result (OUTFILE - typically a .jpg)

```
INFILE=/path/'image name.tif'
OUTFILE=/path/'image name.jpg'

echo INFILE="${INFILE}" OUTFILE="${OUTFILE}" 

magick -quiet "${INFILE}" \
  -filter LanczosRadius \
  -distort resize 1600 \
  -quality 92 \
  "${OUTFILE}"
```

The name of this script is Magick-Resize.sh

I would like to batch process a number of images using this script - that is, run it on multiple INFILES. Eg. If I have 100 images in a folder, I would like each of them to be processed once by this script, producing a unique OUTFILE for each.

I am very much a novice in bash. I gave it a crack with the below:

```
INSCRIPT=/path/Magick-Resize.sh

echo INSCRIPT="${INSCRIPT}"

for INFILE in *.tif; do
    if [[ "$INFILE" = *-tagged.tif ]]; then
        continue # skip output
    fi
    name=$(basename "$INFILE")-tagged.jpg
    echo name="${name}"
    "${INSCRIPT}" "$INFILE" > "${name}"
done
```

But in a test folder containing two .tif images, all it output was one image with the filename "*.jpg"

Is anyone able to provide a solution?

I'm on Mint 20.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I show another way to solve the problem: to modify the original code using `bash`.

- make one single shellscript
- put a shebang at the top, `#!/bin/bash`, to control which shell should run the script
- make a function instead of a separate shellscript of the 'doer' part.
- switch from `magick` to `convert` because that is how the Image Magick tool is implemented in my system. You can easily switch back to run it in your system.
- tweak the batch processing part to make it more robust.

  - add some `# comments` to help understanding what happens. When tagged files are encountered, skip, otherwise create a tagged jpg file
  - the bash variables for the file names are manipulated and tested in order to create only the desired files. This is described in `man bash` at the chapter about Parameter Expansion.

Please notice how the function `doer` is called with two parameters, and how they are seen as `$1` and `$2` in the function.

```
#! /bin/bash -

function doer() {
  INFILE="$1"
  OUTFILE="$2"
  #echo INFILE="${INFILE}" OUTFILE="${OUTFILE}" 
  convert -quiet "${INFILE}" \
    -filter LanczosRadius \
    -distort resize 1600 \
    -quality 92 \
    "${OUTFILE}"
}

#######
# main
#######

shopt -s nullglob
files=(./*.tif)
if (( ${#files[@]} )); then
  # there is at least one tif file, so continue
  for INFILE in "${files[@]}"; do
    if [[ "$INFILE" != *-tagged.tif ]]; then
      # not a tagged tif file, so create variable 'name'
      name="${INFILE%.tif}-tagged.jpg"
      if ! test -s "$name"; then
        # not a tagged jpg file, so create file 'name'
        printf '%s\n' "${name}"
        doer "$INFILE" "${name}"
      fi
    fi
  done
else
  echo >&2 "no tif files found"
  exit 1
fi
echo "normal termination"
```

Comment: `ls *.tif > /dev/null` is not a valid test to check that a glob matches at least one file. `ls -d -- *.tif > /dev/null` would be slightly better, but still not fully correct. In `bash`, you'd do `shopt -s nullglob; files=(*.tif); if (( ${#files[@]} ))...`

Comment: `${INFILE/.tif/-tagged.jpg}` would change `blah.tiffany.tif` to `blah-tagged.jpgfany`. You can do `${INFILE/%.tif/-tagged.jpg}` for the `.tif` to be matched only at the end, though you could also use the standard (also from ksh) `${INFILE%.tif}.jpg`. Similarly, why replace the OP's correct `[[ "$INFILE" = *-tagged.tif ]]`, with that not foolproof and convoluted `[ "$INFILE" == "${INFILE/-tagged.tif}" ]` ?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I have tried to follow your advice, and it works when I tested it 'at home'. Please check if I fixed it correctly.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I notice that there were several more things to modify. Thanks for teaching how to make a foolproof script. Maybe it has reached the highest level now, guruproof ;-)

Comment: Thanks very much, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 4):

Your script doesn't take any argument, the names of the INFILE and OUTFILE are hardcoded within.

Here, I'd use `zsh` instead of `bash`, and do:

```
transform()
  magick -quiet $1 \
   -filter LanczosRadius \
   -distort resize 1600 \
   -quality 92 \
   $2

autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -P transform './(^*-tagged).tif' './$1-tagged.jpg'
```

Comment: Don't you need to quote the positional arguments inside the function?

Comment: @Quasímodo, not in zsh as file names can't be empty strings. Quoting wouldn't harm in any case

Comment: I marked a different response as 'answer' below since it was in bash and allows me to keep the little bash syntax I know to batch other more complex tasks - but for the question asked this solution works perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough for your needs:

First enable `extglob` by running: `shopt -s extglob` and then

```
for i in !(*-tagged).tif; do 
    magick "./$i" <flags> "./${i%%.tif}-tagged.jpg"; 
done
```

This can also be trivially parallelized with GNU parallel:

```
parallel magick ./{} <flags> ./{.}-tagged.jpg ::: !(*-tagged).tif
```

Comment: See [When is double-quoting necessary?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/68694). You'd also need a `./` prefix to the glob to avoid problems with files whose name starts with `-`.

Comment: I probably missed the double quotes when I was typing the command here. I will also add the prefix, although that's a very unusual edge case.